# I broke system tray and Ubuntu dock

Tags: menu, ubuntu-dock, system-tray, autohide

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Yesterday while looking for a package, I found that Evolution was due for an update. Since I never use it, I thought I would uninstall it. Being I was not aware that gnome is now being used as Ubuntu default desktop, I uninstalled other things I thought were associated with that as well.

Now I am getting this message from HPLIP.

> No system tray detected on this system.
> Unable to start, exiting.

There were several programs that had icons on the system tray that are no longer there that I would like to have back.

Additionally, the side dock where favorites are kept no longer autohides and pops out when I run my mouse up against the left edge of my display. I now have to go click on the "Activities" link at the top left corner of the display. I have gone into settings numerous times and set the dock to autohide and every time I go back the setting has been disabled again. I presume this is because the feature is no longer installed.

Does anyone know exactly what package I may have uninstalled that I need for these two issues?

I did re-install a few gnome packages which fixed some things, but not these two.

Comment: Have you looked through your apt logs?  There is a history of what you did.  You should be fine just to reinstall what you removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the necessary packages installed once again by reinstalling the [Ubuntu desktop system](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-desktop). To do that, open a Terminal window and run the following command

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Then reboot your system.

Comment: It is usually something simple, isn't it? That command is what I needed and sure enough, it resolve my issue. Thank you very much. I have been using Linux since 1999, but since Ubuntu cam out and made Linux easy for users, I reverted back to being a user. I am by no means an expert. Everything is back to normal.